# Optimizing of overriding/doting (overridden __getattribute__/__getattr__)

Tags: python, python-2.7

My current code uses the overriding of __getattribute__/__getattr__ for quite often used classes. The profiling indicates that considerable amount of time is spent in the overridden functions. I strongly simplified the code for measurement of performance impact of pure overriding as follows:

```
from timeit import default_timer

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1.0

class Test1(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1.0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return object.__getattribute__(self, item)

class Test2(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 1.0

    def __getattribute__(self, item):
        return super(Test2, self).__getattribute__(item)

class ObjectWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, ocls, obj=None):
        self.__ocls = ocls
        self.__obj = None
        if obj is None or isinstance(obj, ocls):
            self.__obj = obj
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(''.join(str(x) for x in ("The value is ", type(obj), \
                ", but it must be None or instance of ", self.__ocls.__name__)))

    def set_inner_object(self, obj):
        if obj is None or isinstance(obj, self.__ocls):
            self.__obj = obj
        else:
            raise RuntimeError(''.join(str(x) for x in ("The value is ", type(obj), \
                ", but it must be None or instance of ", self.__ocls.__name__)))

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return getattr(self.__obj, name)

def main():
    x = Test()
    x1 = Test1()
    x2 = Test2()
    xw = ObjectWrapper(Test, x)

    accsum = 0.0
    accsum1 = 0.0
    accsum2 = 0.0
    accsumw = 0.0

    s = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(0, 100000000):
        accsum += x.a
    e = default_timer()

    s1 = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(0, 100000000):
        accsum1 += x1.a
    e1 = default_timer()

    s2 = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(0, 100000000):
        accsum2 += x2.a
    e2 = default_timer()

    sw = default_timer()
    for i in xrange(0, 100000000):
        accsumw += xw.a
    ew = default_timer()

    print "speed factor Test1/Test: ", (e1 - s1) / (e - s)
    print "speed factor Test2/Test: ", (e2 - s2) / (e - s)
    print "speed factor Test wrapped/Test: ", (ew - sw) / (e - s)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The impact of overriding is huge. Here is the output:

```
speed factor Test1/Test:  6.32820892871
speed factor Test2/Test:  8.4176175507
speed factor Test wrapped/Test:  11.6202852701
```

Is it normal for Python (python is not my mother programming language) and why?
Is it the price of overriding or/and of doting?!

How can I improve the performance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the more abstraction you use the more things will slow down.  The main Python implementation uses hash tables for everything, and additional levels of indirection often mean additional hash table lookups.

Here is some disassembly for you to chew on:

```
>>> dis.dis(Test2.__getattribute__)
  5           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (super)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (Test2)
              6 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             12 LOAD_ATTR                2 (__getattribute__)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (item)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note that for each `LOAD_GLOBAL` you are basically doing a hash table lookup, and then there's another hash table lookup for `LOAD_ATTR` (I think).  You are doing *much more work* so it takes *much more time*.  Add on top of that the cost of executing a function that you wouldn't otherwise need.